# Launching Activity with noHistory

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I have 2 Activities A and B. A starts B (for B in Manifest I set flag noHistory to true). On Activity B there is single Button that starts DialogFragment (without adding to backStack). 
When dialog is started, and I press Back button on a device I see Activity B, BUT I want to see Activity A.
Temporarily I solved the problem with invoking getActivity.finish() in onCancel() of my Dialog. It works, but I would be more pleased with a better solution. 
I would be grateful for your ideas.

UPDATE: CODE

This is ActivityA:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button btn1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn1.setText("Start Activity2");
    btn1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    setContentView(btn1);
}
```

}

(this is Activity B)

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText("This is Activity 2");
    Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btn.setText("ShowDialog");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.show(fragmentTransaction, "dialog");
        }
    });
    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(btn);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

}

and this is Dialog

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

Activity2 activity = null;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("SomeMessage")
            .setPositiveButton("Fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    if(activity != null)
        activity.finish();
//        getActivity().onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(activity instanceof Activity2) {
        this.activity = (Activity2)activity;
    }
}
```

}

This is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.task_test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"
            android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Dialog"
            android:noHistory="true"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activity3"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: nohistoty true means activity should be removed from the activity stack but you have opened fragment not activity. Then how can u expect on cancel activity should finish()?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan, I I set this flag to Activity, not fragment. And I check onCancel() in DialogFragment class.

Comment: nohistory is for Activities, you are using fragments. You mentioned that you are extending Activity, but that makes no sense considering that you show no startActivity at all in your code. You are using fragments, and therefore the nohistory will not apply.

Comment: @LanaGuts, Even my question is same. U have done onCancel for dilog and ur expecting to finish activity. How it can be possible.? ur assumption of noHistory is wrong

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I do not show code with startActivity() just not to place too much code, so it becomes too heavy to read. I do exactly as I wrote. Activity B I start from Activity A, using Intent with specifying exact class (Activity B) and invoke startActivity(Intent intent) method. For Activity B in my manifest I set noHistory true. First piece of code is from Activity B, that works when I press single button on Activity B, and 2 other pieces are from another class MyDialog, that extends DialogFragment.

Comment: Show your manifest, and can you show more code so that we can understand what you are doing? Question is about transition, displayed code is dialogs

Comment: @Harsha Vardhan. This code that I posted works fine. As it fragment and it is attached to Activity. So in onAttach() I check that the Activity that THIS fragmentdialog is currently attached to, is ActivityB (maybe in other cases, if some other Activity starts this dialog, logic will be different) and cast it to field in MyDialog class. Then, when my dialog is currently visible and user presses BACK buttn, onCancel() is invoked by Android. In that method I do null check and finish ActivityB.

Comment: @LanaGuts,  activity.finish(); is the best one and u have done already.

Comment: @Harsha Vardhan Thanks) I know that this variant is better than previous (with programmatically invoking getActivity().onBackPreesed()), but maybe I do not know about some Android mechanism, that would be better than my manual solution.